# Clear Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Open the app through clicked notification and then clear intent action

If the app in the background, push the local notification and click the notification and open the MainActivity

```
public static void publishLocalNotification(...){
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, "Start")
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.local_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) 
                .setContentText(message);

  resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);

  resultIntent.setAction(action);
  ...
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,-1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

  builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

}


In the Main activity 

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  String action = getIntent().getAction();

  if(action != null){

     ... Show dialog



  }

}
```

If app cannot clear intent action. Each time, when app from background to foreground, the onResume() would be called and the dialog would be shown each time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How clear Android Notification PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878620/how-clear-android-notification-pendingintent)

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

See my extensive discussion of this problem (Persistent data in an `Intent` in a `Notification) here:

[Remove data from notification intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813652/remove-data-from-notification-intent/19820057#19820057)

If you just want to ensure that your dialog is shown once, you can do the following in `onResume()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); // Get the Intent that the app was started with

if (intent.getAction() ) {
    // Show dialog ...
}
intent.setAction(null); // Clear the ACTION in the intent and
setIntent(intent);      //  replace it to prevent the dialog from being shown again
```

But it is possible that I don't understand 100% your requirements.